# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference showing error in this line bellow

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps, heremaps-android-sdk

showing error in this line what can i do showing error in this line what can i do showing error in this line what can i do showing error in this line what can i do showing error in this line what can i do showing error in this line what can i do showing error in this line what can i do showing error in this line what can i do showing error in this line what can i do showing error in this line what can i do showing error in this line what can i do showing error in this line what can i do
`LatLng userLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());`

````
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.icu.text.Replaceable;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import com.example.easyride.R;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MapStyleOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter;
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionDeniedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionGrantedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.single.PermissionListener;

import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {


    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;

    //Location
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private LocationCallback locationCallback;

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        init();

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        return root;
    }

    private void init() {
        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(10f);
        locationRequest.setInterval(5000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(@NonNull LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);

                LatLng newPosition = new LatLng(locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude(),
                        locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude());
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(newPosition, 18f));
            }
        };

        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getContext());
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        //Check Permission
        Dexter.withContext(getContext())
                .withPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            // TODO: Consider calling
                            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                            //                                          int[] grantResults)
                            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                            return;
                        }
                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
                        mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(() -> {
                            fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation()
                                    .addOnFailureListener(e -> Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show())
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(location -> {
                                        LatLng userLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
                                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLatLng,18f));
                                    });
                            return true;
                        });

                        //Set layout button
                        View locationButton = ((View)mapFragment.getView().findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1"))
                                .getParent())
                                .findViewById(Integer.parseInt("2"));
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) locationButton.getLayoutParams();
                        //Right bottom
                        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP,0);
                        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM,RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                        params.setMargins(0,0,0,50);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Permission"+permissionDeniedResponse.getPermissionName()+""+
                                "was denied!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {

                    }
                }).check();

        try {
            boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(getContext(),R.raw.uber_maps_style));
            if (!success)
                Log.e("EDMT_ERROR","Style parsing error");
        }catch (Resources.NotFoundException e){
            Log.e("EDMT_ERROR",e.getMessage());
        }


    }
}```
````

Comment: Please, avoid to repeat text in your question.

Answer (score 0):

***USE THIS CODE***

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.icu.text.Replaceable;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import com.example.uber.R;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MapStyleOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter;
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionDeniedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionGrantedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.single.PermissionListener;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {


    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
    private int requestCode;

    //Location
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private LocationCallback locationCallback;

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        init();

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        return root;
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void init() {
        GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
        googleApiClient.connect();
        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(10f);
        locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(10000 / 2);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(result1 -> {
            final Status status = result1.getStatus();
            if (((Status) status).getStatusCode() == LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED)
                try {
                    status.startResolutionForResult((Activity) getContext(), requestCode);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException ignored) {
                }
        });

        locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(@NonNull LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                LatLng newPosition = new LatLng(locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude(),
                        locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude());
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(newPosition, 18f));
            }
        };

        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getContext());
        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        //Check Permission
        Dexter.withContext(getContext())
                .withPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                    private void onSuccess(Location location) {
                        LatLng userLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLatLng, 18f));
                    }

                    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {
                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
                        mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(() -> {

                            fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation()
                                    .addOnFailureListener(e -> Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show())
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(this::onSuccess);
                            return true;
                        });

                        //Set layout button
                        View locationButton = ((View)mapFragment.getView().findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1"))
                                .getParent())
                                .findViewById(Integer.parseInt("2"));
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) locationButton.getLayoutParams();
                        //Right bottom
                        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP,0);
                        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM,RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                        params.setMargins(0,0,0,50);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Permission"+permissionDeniedResponse.getPermissionName()+""+
                                "was denied!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {

                    }
                }).check();

        try {
            boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(getContext(), R.raw.uber_maps_style));
            if (!success)
                Log.e("EDMT_ERROR","Style parsing error");
        }catch (Resources.NotFoundException e){
            Log.e("EDMT_ERROR",e.getMessage());
        }


    }
}
```